# Solr Search in EE - Search Configurable product by child SKU

Tags: configurable-product, search, solr, ee-1.14.1

I am using EE-1.14.1 with Solr search enabled, and need to set it up so that users can search for the SKU of a simple product, and get shown the configurable product that it is associated with.

These simple products are **not** visible in search.

For example, if I have the following product:

```
Product Name         Type            SKU
--------------------------------------------------------
Chair Red/Green      Configurable    Chair-95
 - Red Chair         Simple          CH95-R
 - Green Chair       Simple          CH95-G
```

...then a search for CH95-R should return the parent product (Chair-95) on the search results page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you think about creating an attribute called "configurable skus" for example. On product save, you fill up this field with a string of all the children SKUs, and you make this field searchable.

Comment: Unfortunately there are around 12,000 SKUs already on the site, so doing this wouldn't be feasible without some significant data-shuffling.

Comment: You can quickly make a script that loops over all your configurable products, and save that data directly in your database. It shouldn't take more than ~30mns to implement & run - as a reference, that question is similar to yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070024/how-do-i-modify-the-magento-search-to-check-child-skus

Comment: I think this might be the best approach, thanks for the advice. Feel free to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an attribute called "configurable_skus" for example. On product save, you fill up this field with a string of all the children SKUs, and you make this field searchable.

Comment: I like this idea but it poses a problem with the returned product page from search.... It returns the configurable product page and does not pre-select the options associated with that sku.  A very clever suggestion though!